# how can I use a .exe file in android os?

Tags: android

is it possible to use and run a ,exe file in android?

I know the cpu diferences between an smart phone and a PC 
and the exe file may use a systemic dll file

how can I do this? is it possible?

Comment: **NO**. Forget about that. `I know the cpu diferences between an smart phone and a PC` That's not the point. The **OS** is different. An exe will never work on an Android device, unless you don't have an emulator (someone said `Virtual Machine`?) to run Windows  Portable Executables

Comment: realy it is impossible?

Comment: http://smallbusiness.chron.com/make-exe-files-work-android-phone-42277.html

Comment: how about wine? can I use this on android to run .exe x86 files ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an emulator for DOS based exes. Something like this DosBox
http://androiddosbox.appspot.com/

Answer (score 1):

Executable files ending with (.exe) cannot run on Android easily because these files are associated with Windows based Systems, Android is based on Linux. Although installing [DOSBOX](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fishstix.dosboxlauncher&hl=en) on your phone might allow this. There is also this pretty long-winded way of doing it if its pretty useful to you - http://smallbusiness.chron.com/make-exe-files-work-android-phone-42277.html

Comment: try that link. DosBox is emulating DOS on Android. There is a pretty slim chance of your executables working. Come to think of it Although I don't own a Windows Phone , I wonder if even those can run .exe files (probably not since the mobile version is related to its desktop cousin only in name)